# Symfony 1 - How to make a link from a foreach

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am really new to Symfony 1. I know it's old and that support has ended for this version. But one of the projects at the company where I do my internship still runs on symfony 1.4.

I have a foreach loop;

```
<?php foreach ($configuration->getFormFields($form, 'show') as $fieldset => $fields): ?>
        <?php //include_partial('service/form_fieldset', array('service' => $service, 'form' => $form, 'fields' => $fields, 'fieldset' => $fieldset)) ?>

        <table id="sf_fieldset_<?php echo preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]/', '_', strtolower($fieldset)) ?>" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sf_admin_st">
            <tr>
                <th>Property</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($fields as $name => $field):

                ?>
                <?php $i++;
                $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';

                ?>

                <?php $attributes = $field->getConfig('attributes', array()); ?>
                <?php if ($field->isPartial()): ?>
                    <?php include_partial('service/' . $name, array('service' => $service, 'form' => $form, 'attributes' => $attributes instanceof sfOutputEscaper ? $attributes->getRawValue() : $attributes)) ?>
                <?php elseif ($field->isComponent()): ?>
                    <?php include_component('service', $name, array('service' => $service, 'form' => $form, 'attributes' => $attributes instanceof sfOutputEscaper ? $attributes->getRawValue() : $attributes)) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo $class ?>">
                        <td><?php echo $field->getConfig('label') ? $field->getConfig('label') : $field->getName() ?>:</td>
                        <td><?php echo $form->getObject()->get($name) ? $form->getObject()->get($name) : "-" ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

the above mentioned code output table below;

[image: Output Table]

My question is, how can I make a field in the table a link to that specific description. I want the `Parent Service` value in the table to become a link to that specific value.

I have thought of an if, like this;

```
<?php if ($field->getConfig('label') == "parent_service_description"): ?>
                            <td><a href="#"><?php echo $form->getObject()->get($name) ? $form->getObject()->get($name) : "-" ?></a></td>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <td><?php echo $form->getObject()->get($name) ? $form->getObject()->get($name) : "-" ?></td>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

But my knowledge still lacks a lot to figure this out. I'll really appreciate some help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got a route to the details page I would try something like this using url_for and a given $parentId:

```
<?php if ($field->getConfig('label') == "parent_service_description"): ?>
<td>
   <a href="<?php echo url_for('@show_details?id=' . $parentId) ?>">
      <?php echo $form->getObject()->get($name) ? $form->getObject()->get($name) : "-" ?>
   </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, I see I am going in the right direction. (I hope :D)

Answer (score 0):

You should use.

```
echo link_to ($name, "action/module?id=". $sf_params->get("id") . "&params2=2") )
```

the reason behind is its readability and simplicity.